# Android, slidingmenu, responsivity fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I've found following code in [slidingmenu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) examples, in `ResponsiveUIActivity.java`, I don't know what is `if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) {` mean:

```
// check if the content frame contains the menu frame
if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) {
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(true);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    // show home as up so we can toggle
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
} else {
    // add a dummy view
    View v = new View(this);
    setBehindContentView(v);
    getSlidingMenu().setSlidingEnabled(false);
    getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
}
```

the `R.id.menu_frame` points to 3 layouts
this one is in `layout` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

this one is in `layout-xlarge` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width = "match_parent"
              android:layout_height = "match_parent"
              android:orientation = "horizontal"
              android:baselineAligned = "true">

  <FrameLayout
      android:id = "@+id/menu_frame"
      android:layout_width = "0dp"
      android:layout_height = "match_parent"
      android:layout_weight = "1" />

  <FrameLayout
      android:id = "@+id/content_frame"
      android:layout_width = "0dp"
      android:layout_height = "match_parent"
      android:layout_weight = "2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this one is in `layout-large-land` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in 3 of above layouts `menu_frame` is null but how sliding menu works with theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout directories `layout`, `layout-xlarge`, and  `layout-large-land` indicates the different layouts for supporting screen size and screen orientation. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

The condition, `if(findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null)` is checking if the `view` exists or not.

That is, if the condition holds `true`, it indicates that the sliding menu is currently closed and thus you're placing the `menu view` "behind" the `current view`. However, when the condition is `false`, it indicates that the user has tapped on the menu button on the top-left corner and thus executes the `else` part, which places the `current view` "behind" and brings up the `menu view`.

Comment: It's wrong **answer**, I look to the code over and over again and the answer is here `setContentView(R.layout.responsive_content_frame);` this code runs befor the (`if`) i've wrote in my question, there is 3 layouts in `layout`, `layout-xlarge` and `layout-large-land` and there is now element with `menu_frame` id in `layout\responsive_content_frame.xml` I don't know but i think the `findViewById()` method in some where is in relation with `setContentView()` method. is this theory correct ?

Comment: That was my explanation to your question "**what is if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) { mean**"

Comment: Yeah, Thanks :) and I've found **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476424/why-findviewbyid-is-returning-null-if-setcontentview-is-not-called)**. could you please read it ?

Comment: @OMiD In a nutshell, when a particular view is not associated to the current context (or Activity), then findViewById() will return null.

Comment: YEY :-* that's what I'm lookin' for. now I do exactly know why `if (findViewById(R.id.menu_frame) == null) {` used here :) really thanks.